# Having a check box update fields in a table

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

frustrated by vba...

I am trying to have user click a check box on a form which indicates whether a support ticket as been resolved, along with the date resolved and which user clicks the check box.

I have used `WScript.UserName` to get the network ID in a variable GetUserName.

I have two fields in my table:

ResolvedDate
ResolvedBy

I want both these fields filled in with appropriate data when the check box is True, and if the check box is False then I want the data removed.

Here is the code I have used:

```
Dim GetUserName As String
GetUserName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
Text45.Text = GetUserName
End Sub
```

Note the Text45 is a visual on the form which displays the user name (this is showing blank) and shows me a message about not being able to reference a property unless it has focus.  That is problem 2.

Additional code for the check box looks like this:

```
Dim GetUserName As String
If Resolved = 1 Then
    ResolvedDate.Text = Now()
    ResolvedBy.Text = GetUserName
End If
End Sub
```

Nothing works here at all.  I have also tried changing the code to

```
Dim GetUserName As String
If Resolved = 1 Then
    ResolvedDate.Text = Now()
    ResolvedBy.Text = text45.Text
End If
End Sub
```

Because the GetUserName() is private in the Form_Onload() event I have also duplicated it on the check box AfterUpdate() event but it still didn't work. (I know - not efficient coding)

I cannot fathom out what to do to hold data in a value after it has lost focus to use it somewhere else, and I cannot get these fields to complete.

Can someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: Use .Value instead of .Text

Comment: Thank you!! That worked!! Was that the reason for getting the SetFocus error as well?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `.Text` is only available when the control has the focus.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for the delay in replying.